# Why can't the compiler optimize a single throw statement in a try-catch block?

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, try-catch, compiler-optimization

I was just playing around with some C++ code at [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org) and noticed some unexpected behavior when compiling a simple `try`/`catch` block. Both of the following snippets were compiled with gcc using optimization flag `-O3` ([live example](https://godbolt.org/z/43eE79Yro)).

In the first program, the whole `try`/`catch` block gets removed, since there is no noticeable difference in the behavior, resulting in the same assembly as just a `return 0;`. This is exactly what I would have expected the compiler to produce.

```
int main() {
    try {
        int x{ 10 };
    }
    catch (...) {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

In the second snippet I `throw` an exception instead of just initializing an `int`. After that exception got thrown, I would continue in the `catch`-all handler, which is empty. After that there is only the `return 0;` statement. This means that the observable behavior for this program would be the same as the first one. However, the assembly shows, that there is still the whole `try`/`catch` going on.

```
int main() {
    try {
        throw 10;
    }
    catch (...) {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
main:
        push    rcx
        mov     edi, 4
        call    __cxa_allocate_exception
        xor     edx, edx
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZTIi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 10
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    __cxa_throw
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    __cxa_begin_catch
        call    __cxa_end_catch
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rdx
        ret
```

Now I am wondering why the compiler can't recognize that the whole `try`/`catch` block is "dead code" (or is it not?), or if it can recognize it, why it is not optimizing it away.

Comment: There is a global "in flight" exception.  Your `throw 10;` will *copy* that 10 literal to the in flight `int` exception with the value 10.  I recall that the exception machinery can be hooked into.  Perhaps it can't be optimized out, even though your code is complete and self-contained, and doesn't hook into that exception machinery.

Comment: I think this is the "lowest hanging fruit" syndrome. Of all the possible optimizations in C++ code, being able to optimize away an exception entirely probably carries the least possible likelyhood of happening. As such, the suffering compiler developers have chosen to apply their limited energies towards more productive avenues, and focus on improving other kinds of optimizations. It's also doubtful that this is the only kind of an optimization that seems obvious to a meatbag's brain, but is surprisingly difficult, logically, to define and implement.

Comment: MSVC is able to do that: https://godbolt.org/z/orsceoW3W (`main` just zeros EAX).

Comment: @MarekR, are you looking at `LN7@main`? In the `main PROC` it's still throwing; though it does get rid of the catch.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38658

Comment: @MarekR: As ChrisMM points out, that' just the catch/return block.  If you change it to `catch(char c)` (which doesn't catch the throw of an `int` so the program crashes instead), MSVC's code-gen is the same: https://godbolt.org/z/56nd1cffd